# Windows cannot create shortcut when installing Haskell Platform (core)

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, administrator, windows-error-reporting

So I'm trying to install [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/downloads) in Windows 10, and unfortunately I have neither internet access nor administrator privileges.  I tried to install it, and it did not require admin privileges to install, but it said that it recommends to be admin when installing.  It seemed to work installing it, but at the end it gave an error in the show details that said "error creating shortcut in windows/program files" (paraphrasing).  Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? If it is trying to create a file in the Program Files folder, it needs admin privileges to do so (i.e. run the installation as administrator).

Comment: I cannot.  I could reinstall it, but i'm not sure what that would do to my pc

Comment: @FastEthernet could it possibly install correctly if I did it in, say users or documents?

Comment: Where did you choose to install it in the first place? The default location (which seems to be in the AppData folder) should work just fine.

Comment: Appdata was where I installed it.

Comment: The only thing that appears there is Haskell Stack